# Removing a USB device but leaving power?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I have a dashcam in my RV that is plugged into my Asus Tinkerboard (like an RPi). It is getting power from the usb port of the tinker. I would like to leave it connected to the tinker so that I can access the files remotely. The problem is that the camera detects access of the file system and switches into 'USB Connected mode' on the camera which disables the recording of videos.

What I am looking for is a way to still provide power to the camera, but not be connected in any sense to the filesystem.

I have tried unbinding from usb-storage but the camera still thinks it is in filesystem access mode.

```
root@tinkerbell:~# echo -n "1-1.4:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/unbind
root@tinkerbell:~# tree /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/
/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage/
├── 1-1.3:1.0 -> ../../../../devices/platform/ff540000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0
├── bind
├── module -> ../../../../module/usb_storage
├── new_id
├── remove_id
├── uevent
└── unbind
```